# Nuitka compile python project that has sub-directories that contain needed files

Tags: python, directory, compilation, nuitka

I have a python project that has the following structure:

[image]

I am using the following for compilation, `python -m nuitka --follow-imports --standalone C:\Users\probat\Documents\main.py`

The project is being compiled as a standalone executeable so I also need to include `Sub-Directory` and also its contents (`rules.txt` and `settings.ini`) - these are not being included currently. I know I am obviously in fault here but after reading the user documentation and searching everywhere I failed to find a solution. I tried using `--include-plugin-directory` but that didn't work. I may not be using it correctly or I am wrong for using it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I just copy the folder and its contents after the compilation is done. This is part of the workflow. I did the same with PyInstaller, so it does not seem awful to me.

Comment: You do that when you compile as a directory build I presume. I should have mentioned above that I am compiling as a standalone executeable file so I need to include the subdirectory as a part of the standalone binary that is output. I did mention '--standalone' option above. I'll edit the question to make this more explicit.